# Please guys can you help me with this question? I've been trying to solve it for days.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the set of vectors $[2x-3y,x+2y,-y,-4x]$ with $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Addition and scalar multiplication are defined in the same way as in vectors.

Prove that $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: $V$ is not a vector space, because it is not closed under addition or scalar multiplication. Or did you mean the linear span of $V$?

Comment: The $0$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is in $V$ by taking $x=y=0$. If you sum the vectors in $V$ produced by taking $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, the sum is the vector in $V$ produced by $(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$. Likewise the product of the vector in $V$ produced by $(x,y)$ with the scalar $r$ is the vector of $V$ produced by $(rx,ry)$. Therefore $V$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ that contains $0$ and is closed by addition and multiplication by a scalar. Therefore, it is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. In particular it is a vector space.

Comment: If you sum $[2x_1-3y_1,x_1+2y_1,-y_1,-4x_1]+[2x_2-3y_2,x_2+2y_2,-y_2,-4x_2]$ you get $[2(x_1+x_2)-3(y_1+y_2),(x_1+x_2)+2(y_1+y_2),-(y_1+y_2),-4(x_1+x_2)]$. If you multiply by a scalar $r[2x-3y,x+2y,-y,-4x]$ you get $[2(rx)-3(ry),(rx)+2(ry),-(ry),-4(rx)]$.

Comment: So I don't need to prove the 10 laws of vector space?

Comment: It’s considered bad form here to repost [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3488600/265466) verbatim after it’s been closed for lack of context. It’s likely going to get closed again unless to improve in the ways suggested [in this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/).

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix} 2&-3\\1&2\\0&-1\\-4&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix}$ gives you all the vectors you need.

Now the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 2&-3\\1&2\\0&-1\\-4&0 \end{bmatrix}$ defines a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^4}$.

And we know that image of a linear transformation from one vector space to another is a vector space.

Comment: So I don't need to prove the 10 laws of vector space?

Comment: Use your 10 laws to prove the statement I made in the last line.Then use it whenever you need it.